# Sample web server and the endianness

Tags: c++, c, sockets, openssl, network-programming

I have built a very sample web server with non-blocking sockets as command line program for Mac.

The main programming language i'm using is C++, but also C in some cases.

I'm also using the OpenSSL library so the clients can use "https" in the web browser.

The web server works and the clients can access it from a web browser and they will see "Hello world" displayed.

Portability is very important for me and my questions is:

- Is there any endian issues here ( becouse i'm using my program only as web server ) that i most prevent first?
- Do i need to use htonl() when sending and ntohl() when i'm reading ?
- As i understand the images is always sent as binary ( is there any other files too that should be sent as binary? ), but the index.html etc is sent as strings. So i have to use htonl() only on the images?

Thank you for giving me your time i hope someone can explain to me the above questions easy as i'm interested in understanding how things should be done correct.

Comment: Text is usually not endianess dependent (unless you use UTF-16 or -32, which you really should not do). And any other data you should send as-is, without any processing.

Comment: Also if you are sending protocol HTTP/2 which is based on binary?

Comment: ALL data send over HTTP is binary in nature, even text.  HTTP doesn't make a distinction in message bodies, it only cares about raw bytes.  That is why the HTTP headers have entries like `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` to describe what those raw bytes represent, `Transfer-Encoding` to describe what format the bytes are transmitted in, etc.

Comment: What if html file contains a non-utf-8 character like utf-16?  is "text is usually not endianess dependent" still true in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to worry about endianness when you have a *binary* protocol.  For example if you send an integer as a 32-bit value then you need to worry about the byte order.

Because HTTP is a text protocol, you don't need to worry about endianness when sending or receiving data.  In the case of binary files being transmitted such as images, files are just a sequence of bytes so you send and receive them as-is.  If the file format has any endianness involved, that is for programs that process the file content to worry about, not programs that are simply sending or receiving.

Comment: What about if there is HTTP/2  support?  i'm asking this becouse  it's based on binary

Comment: @annap. If there are binary components to the protocol itself then you need to worry about byte order for those fields, but not for content.

Comment: so just to confirm. Plain text protocol such as  HTTP 1.1 there is no need to worry about the endianness, but binary protocol such as HTTP/2 one should worry about the  endianness?

Comment: @annap. Correct.  Fields specified as binary in the procotol are the ones where byte order is important.

Comment: Great thank you very much @dbush, now i understand it much better!

Comment: HTTP is not a text protocol. It has some textual elements, such as message headers, chunk headers, etc, but everything in a message body is typically treated as raw bytes, regardless of what they represent (aside from things like MIME and chunking). You don't generally need to worry about endian issues in HTTP 1.x, but in HTTP/2 you definitely do since it has binary elements that carry multi-byte numeric values (frame lengths, stream identifiers, etc).

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you explaining it! :) what does it mean " Text is usually not endianess dependent (unless you use UTF-16 or -32, which you really should not do).  " when is the text UTF-16 or -32 is it the data type? i'm using std::string

Comment: @annap. UTFs are byte encodings for Unicode, where the number in their names specify how many bits they use for their elements. UTFs greater than 8 bits suffer from endian and thus are less desirable for cross platform exchanges. It is very rare to see UTF-16/32 used in Internet protocols, whereas UTF-8 is very common. On the other hand, UTF-16 is very common in APIs, as it is easier to process than UTF-8. Some protocols use less common UTFs, like UTF-7 in IMAP, but that is slowly being phased out in favor of UTF-8.